# Linking ".." do somewhere other than parent directory and other strange fs beharviors

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, directory-structure, posix

Can the entry ".." become linked to someplace other than the parent directory?  Is it possible to cause "tar" to create this weird behavior?

Scenario: I have a pre-built compiler to a embeded system, distributed as tar.gz files, which works perfectly in Ubuntu 10.04. When testing an upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 in a VirtualBox VM, it failed to find out some header files. Exploring the files for the cause of the problem, I noticed it became lost following "/a/somewhat/convoluted/../../path/../full/of/up/../references/". Exploring a bit more, I found some strange behavior:

- "ls /that/strange/../../path"  shows me the files as expected.
- typing "ls /that/strange/../../path"  in bash for a list of files inside "/that/strange/../../path" (ie, triggering the filename completion without running "ls") shows me a DIFFERENT list of files.
- when I fix the path interpreting the ".." by hand, both outputs are the same.

I suppose "ls" and the filename globbing differ in the way they find the files (opendir/readdir, glob, etc.) and one of these operations steps in a filesystem error. Running fsck in the VM resulted in nothing unusual. Same result for installing the compiler again in a new VM. "tar" returned no error. Do somebody got this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is one of the "directories" in your path actually a symbolic link to some other directory? If so, then `..` will go to the parent directory of the target directory, not to the directory containing the symbolic link.

Bash tries to "fix" this by reinterpreting `..` to mean the directory containing the symlink. I'm sure there's a way to turn this annoying behavior off, though I don't have it handy as I can't remember the last time I personally had to deal with this.